# What's the fastest way to install packages using YUM that you don't know the full name of?

Tags: software-installation, yum

I could just search each thing for example, I tried:

```
sudo yum install -y \
  java javascript nodejs apache c c++
```

All came back as not found.

it would be tedious to search for each package, and I was wondering if there are any tricks that can be used to quickly get each package name.

I have a whole bunch of things I need to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use patterns to match packages, *e.g.* `*java*`, but that won’t help: they match *any* package containing the strings you’re looking for. Consider `java` and `javascript`: the latter contains the former, so installing packages matching the former would install packages matching the latter... And `c` of course would match any package containing the letter “c”.

You really do need to go through the “tedium” of searching for each package, and tell `yum` specifically the packages you really want.